# Why are Last.fm's features unavailable to Banshee users who don't subscribe to the service?

Tags: banshee

Whenever I try to do anything other view my Last.fm profile in Banshee, I am confronted with the following message at the bottom of the inteface:

```
Failed to tune into station: Stations are only available to paying Last.fm subscribers
```

These are features I've been able to use in both the Last.fm client from the Software Center and the Rhythmbox plugin. I can also go to the website and listen there. What gives?

**Update**: To clarify, I have a Last.fm account, but am not a paying subscriber.

Following a [link](http://blog.last.fm/2009/03/24/lastfm-radio-announcement) in the answer provided by [DoR](https://askubuntu.com/users/114/dor), it seems Last.fm changed the structure of their service to be restricted outside of the US, UK and Germany, but I am in the UK so this still just as confusing.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please?  Is it that you have an account with Last.fm, but not a paying account?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Banshee uses a newer version of the Last.fm API which requires you to be a subscriber, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=541227. Rhythmbox uses (or did anyway) a deprecated version of the API that did not require you to subscribe to Last.fm.

Comment: I've just tried playing my 'Recommended' station in the Last.fm dedicated client and it worked there, when it doesn't work in the Banshee plugin, and doesn't appear to be available in the Rhythmbox plugin. Am I correct in assuming Last.fm are keeping this feature (and others) for themselves?

Comment: I realize this is a bit old, but just for completeness... Chris, you're right, the official Last.fm client is not limited to the restrictions of the new API.  Third-party applications, such as Banshee, have to follow these API guidelines, which only allow radio for paying subscribers: http://www.last.fm/api/radio

Answer (score -2):

Because you don't subscribe to last.fm. Last.fm requires you to subscribe to use those features, so it's not Banshee, it's last.fm.